# Google App Engine (PHP) - How to include javascript

Tags: php, javascript, google-app-engine

I made website using PHP on LAMP server and now I want to put it on GAE but it seems it can't recognize javascript. This is my yaml file:

```
application: helloworld
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /stylesheets
  static_dir: stylesheets

- url: /.*
  script: index.php

- url: /js
  static_dir: js
```

Then in html I load it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
```

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the app.yaml file, the first matching URL regular expression will be executed. As you have the catch all .* expression above the /js then it will match the request.

Change the order of you app.yaml to

```
handlers:

- url: /stylesheets
  static_dir: stylesheets

- url: /js
  static_dir: js

- url: /.*
  script: index.php
```

Comment: It's still not working, is there anything I have to put in javascript file to make it run on GAE. Everything works perfectly on LAMP.

Comment: I fixed it, I forgot to make handler for another .js file which I needed. Thank you